# Finding location of corner points at starting and ending of curvature(matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, corner-detection

I want to find corner points at the ending and starting of the curvature (stroke).
First, I apply corner detection algorithm to find corners.(It may find unwanted points and also may lose some corner points). Now I want to choose some points from these detected corners- points that is on the starting and ending part of stroke(as showing in left image with orange line). I used

```
findpeaks(vertical_profile_projection);
```

to find the approximate position of  desired points but it does not always work.[image: Image I used]

In the left image you see corner points and desired points and right image shows  two lines where we have maximum peaks.
The image is like rotated letter 'C' that may have different shape in different fonts
Give me solution to find these desired points.
Thanks.

EDIT1:
Raw image and another sample is added. Note:In my process minimum component is removed. Read image in Matlab like below:

```
[~,~,image]=imread('E:\a.png');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you also upload the image without any marks/drawings on it?